# checking textField info in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a UIImage next to a text field. I want the image to change (to a check) if the text field passes a format test. So, if there are six characters entered, the image will change. I tried to use textFieldDidChange but I think this function only gets called once the field changes the first time. Is there a function I can use that gets called every time a character is entered? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an action on the editing changed event. This can be accomplished through an IBAction or by adding a target manually.

**IBAction**

Add this method in your view controller and connect the outlet to the editingChanged event in your xib or storyboard:

```
@IBAction func textFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Your code here
}
```

**Add Target**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

func textFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used the IBAction with an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield). Under the **Discussion** section, it says,

> The text field calls this method whenever user actions cause its text to change. Use this method to validate text as it is typed by the user.

"This method" refers to `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

This is the full method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    <code>
}
```